# C++ - How to convert char* to std::list<char>

Tags: c++, chars, stdlist

This is a beginner type of question

I'm just wondering if there is a way to convert a null terminated char* to std::list.

Thank you

```
char* data = ...
std::list<char> clist = convert_chars2list(data);
...
convert_chars2list(char* somedata)
{
    //convert
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::list<char> convert_chars2list(char *somedata)
{
    std::list<char> l;

    while(*somedata != 0)
        l.push_back(*somedata++);

    // If you want to add a terminating NULL character
    // in your list, uncomment the following statement:
    // l.push_back(0);

    return l;
}
```

Comment: `l.push_back(*somedata++);`: Isn't this Undefined Behavior? The side effect of `operator ++` is not sequenced before the evaluation the argument of `operator *`... or am I confused?

Comment: @NikBougalis: I always get confused even with this simple stuff: so is it `*(somedata++)` or `(*somedata)++`? In the first case I believe it is UB, because the side effect of `++` is unsequenced wrt to the value computation of `*`. I believe...

Comment: @AndyProwl actually I was wrong. According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence *postfix* `++` has a higher precedence that `*`. I don't think this is UB - franly, I'd be surprised if it were since it's such a commonly used idiom. But you do have me thinking; I'll have to research this more closely now I think.

Comment: Well, the side-effect of incrementing `somedata` is not sequenced before the value computation of `*(somedata++)`. At least I believe so. So that should be UB... but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I got it wrong too, even after looking it up! The moral is that you basically shouldn't do things like this because it's too easy to misunderstand; however, this is an exception because it's a common idiom that programmers know works even if they don't know all the rules that make it work off the top of their heads.

Comment: @AndyProwl: It doesn't matter when the side-effect happens. It has no effect on the result.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Hm, on the one hand I know this *must* work, on the other hand I can't see why. I thought since `operator ++` has a side-effect on the object `somedata`, and `operator *` performs a value computation that depends on the value of the object `somedata`, this would be UB per 1.9/15: *"If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: I think I'm going to post a question about this and hopefully get some of the C++ gurus on here to chime in.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Oh, I got it. `operator *` does not perform a value computation that depends on the value of the object `somedata`. The value computation depends on the value returned by `somedata++`. So that's not UB. Damn, I think I'll never learn this stuff

Comment: @NikBougalis: Don't do that: you'll most likely get stoned by people pissed off at how many times these things have been repeated over and over again :-)

Comment: Woe... my dreams of a "Famous Question" gold badge evaporated.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably the simplest way:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main() 
{ 
    char const* data = "Hello world";
    std::list<char> l(data, data + strlen(data));
}
```

It exploits the fact that `std::string` has an interface which is compatible with STL containers.

Comment: A better solution that mine.

Comment: That works? I would have thought you needed to use iterators.

Comment: Doing it this way does give a warning with vs2010. warning C4930: 'std::list<_Ty> l(std::string)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Comment: @Caesar, Yeah, that's a sign of the MVP. `l` is a function with that declaration.

Comment: While doing it this way is quick in term of typing, I think it is not the most optimal option just because a string has to be allocated and than a list.

Comment: @Caesar: That's correct. In fact, I wrote this is probably the "simplest" way. I believe you should always favor simplicity, unless you are really concerned with performance. There is no evidence here that this would be a performance-critical operation. Hence, my choice.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you just do `data, data + strlen(data) + 1`? Will avoid extra allocations, and seems just as readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<char> convert_chars2list(char* somedata)
{
  std::list<char> res;
  while (*somedata)
     res.push_back(*somedata++);
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `char*` is a C-style string than you can do this (that means it ends with a `\0`)

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    char hello[] = "Hello World!";

    std::list<char> helloList;

    for(int index = 0; hello[index] != 0; ++index)
    {
        helloList.push_back( hello[index] );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let C++ standard library take care of pointer handling and iterator traversing.

```
std::string str = "Hello world";
```

Though you can access each character with [] operator from std::string itself, if you want a list of characters

```
std::list<char> chars(str.begin(), str.end());
```

Answer (score -1):

It's really weird to use a std::list to contain characters, if you really want to use stl to contain characters, you could use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), which would allow you to do:

```
char*           data = ....;
std::string     string(data);
```